# TSLint inline rules stop working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rules, tslint

I have a setup VS Code + TSLint extension on my work and it works perfectly.
No i work from home, did the same setup, but found that inline rules stop working at home setup, for example TS Lint says me that i should use self-closed tag for `<script>`, i want to ignore it and add `// tslint:disable-next-line: jsx-self-close`, but as you can see on screen shot the warning with underline still exists:

[image]

This also true for any other inline rules. 
Since i have  `"source.fixAll.tslint": true` in vs code `settings.json` it always fix it in unwanted way for me.
I try to googled about it but can't find similar issues

Also here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/typings",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "./src/public"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The placement of comment was wrong, the correct placement is:

```
// tslint:disable: jsx-self-close
export const AmpAnalytics = React.memo(() => (
    <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
        <script
            type="application/json"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: json }}
        >
        </script>
    </amp-analytics>
));
```